# Possible to set reply-to address different than from address in grails mail plugin?

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, grails, amazon-ses

I'm using the Grails mail plugin to send email through Amazon SES.  Amazon SES enforces the 'from' address to be verified, meaning a domain under my control, which is fine, but much of the mail I send is on behalf of customers in the system who want any reply to go directly to them.  Given this, I would like to set the reply-to differently than the from, is this possible in Grails mail plugin?

So the email would end up being

```
From: noreply@domainThatIControl.com
Reply-To:  customer@customersDomain.com
Subject: ...
Body: ...
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yep, just use replyTo

```
sendMail {
  to 'someone@somewhere.com'
  replyTo 'customer@customersDomain.com'
  subject "some mail"
  from 'noreply@domainThatIControl.com'
  body "some body"
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks, not sure why this isn't in the docs!